# Safari 5 extension for site-specific CSS customisation?

Tags: safari, css, browser-addons

Is there a Safari 5 extension along the lines of [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/)? Basically a way to quickly install or create site-specific CSS files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Feel free to install my [Stylish](http://sobolev.us/stylish/) extension for Safari (also available in Apple Extensions gallery, Developer section) or fork my project on [GitHub](https://github.com/350d/stylish).

Extension in development, but you can create new styles, search/manage/edit styles from user styles.org database, styles options - only default values supported in current version.

Comment: What's the status of this?  The extensions gallery has been replaced by the app store, and I can't find it there.

Comment: Unfortunatelly Apple turned Stylish Safari extension off. By any chance, can someone tell me where my custom CSS were stored by it while I was using it? Had a lot off custom CSS that I really would like to get back.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.grid.in.th/

Thanks to http://safariextensions.tumblr.com/post/687054388/post-user-css-06-11-10

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though an independent developer has ported or rewritten [Stylish as a Safari extension](http://sobolev.us/stylish/)! It is currently in beta according to the developer.